# How to Avoid TypeError on not extensible object when using chartsJs

Tags: angular5, chart.js, ngrx-store

I'm having an issue in my project which uses *Angular 5*, *NgRx*,  materialDesignBootstrap and *chartsjs*.

Essentially, when the charts are created, I get a list of console messages like the following (the charts properly display anyway):

> Attempting to configure '_chartjs' with descriptor '[object Object]' on object '17.94,17.47,17.14,17.17,18.21,17.91,18.34,20.25,21.39' and got error, giving up: TypeError: Cannot define property _chartjs, object is not extensible      -  zone.js:2228
>
> Attempting to configure 'push' with descriptor '{"configurable":true,"enumerable":false}' on object '17.94,17.47,17.14,17.17,18.21,17.91,18.34,20.25,21.39' and got error, giving up: TypeError: Cannot define property push, object is not extensible   -  zone.js:2228
>
> Attempting to configure 'pop' with descriptor '{"configurable":true,"enumerable":false}' on object '17.94,17.47,17.14,17.17,18.21,17.91,18.34,20.25,21.39' and got error, giving up: TypeError: Cannot define property pop, object is not extensible -  zone.js:2228

After a short investigation I read the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Cant_define_property_object_not_extensible) about frozen object and found the code throwing these messages inside the chartsJs node_module folder, but i really don't know how to solve the issue.

Here is the charts markup:

```
<canvas mdbChart *ngIf="chartsData.length >= 1"
    [chartType]="chartType"
    [datasets]="chartsData" 
    [labels]="xLabels"
    [colors]="chartColors"
    [options]="chartOptions"
    [legend]="chartsData && chartsData.length >= 1"
    (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)" 
    (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)">
</canvas>
```

and here is a piece of the ts file:

```
@Input() chartData: Array<object>; 
@Input() xLabel: Array<string>; 
xLabels: Array<string>; 
chartsData: Array<object>; 

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if( changes.xLabel && changes.xLabel.currentValue.length > 0 && changes.chartData && changes.chartData.currentValue.length > 0 ){
        this.chartsData = changes.chartData.currentValue.map(item => Object.assign({}, item));
        /** this workaround solves a mdb library bug  not updating xAxis label*/
        setTimeout(function () {
            this.xLabels = changes.xLabel.currentValue.slice(0);
        }.bind(this), 0);
    }
}
```

as you can see above, i tried to clone the input objects (they both come from the ngRx state), but it didn't solve the issue.

I'll be happy to provide any needed information. And I'm sorry if this is not quite a workable example, but you probably know it would require a tons of files to make an angular 5 working example xD

Comment: hello Koop4 did you solve the problem yet? Because i'm experiencing the same problem! With me the problem occurs when I store the last visited child component url in localstorage and then reload that child component url when the parent url/component is loaded. This problem does not occur when i change the default chart values to something else and then store that in local storage

Comment: U can remove the store freeze (that was causing the problem in my case). It could also be the environment setting related to ngrx.